# VSCode Error Decoration Defaults to Text Opacity (instead of underline squiggly)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tslint

My TSLint no-unused setting is causing the editor to show the warnings as reduced opacity instead of underline.

I want the warning to show as underline, but I can't seem to find a setting to change that.

[image]

I know the underline warning works, because for spellchecker it underlines. But it's not applying that for TSLint unused variables.

https://gyazo.com/1d2f0a629db5db1257973a83fb7e5432

Comment: Are you sure the unused variables are being reported by ts-lint, or are they coming from typescript? When you hover over the error, what is its source?

Comment: @MattBierner yeah you're correct it's coming from typescript, as shown in the gyazo gif. Does that changes things? https://gyazo.com/1d2f0a629db5db1257973a83fb7e5432

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unused variables are reported by VS Code's built-in JavaScript and TypeScript support. To make them more visible, tell TypeScript to treat these as error/warnings with the `noUnusedLocals` and `noUnusedParameters` compiler options your project's `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2016",
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can configure a custom border color for them in VS code with `workbench.colorCustomizations`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#f0f",
    "editorUnnecessaryCode.opacity": "#000f"
}
```

This adds a bottom border to unused variables without turning them into compiler errors/warnings